# Error Implementing force:showToast - Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="num1"/> +
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="num2"/>
    <br/>
    <ui:button label="Add" press="{!c.showToast}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
  ({
        showToast : function(component, event, helper) {
        var n1 = component.find("num1").get("v.value");
        var n2 = component.find("num2").get("v.value");

        // Display the total in a "toast" status message

        var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        resultsToast.setParams({
            "title": "Quick Add: " + n1 + " + " + n2,
            "message": "The total is: " + (n1 + n2) + "."
        });
        resultsToast.fire();

        // Close the action panel

        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        }
    })
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c$TestCheck1$controller$showToast [Cannot read property
>   'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c$TestCheck1$controller$showToast}

Comment: how are you running the component? Is it inside a vf page?

Comment: No not in a vf in an aura:application I'm calling this component

Comment: As Phil points standard force event like force:showToast will not work in lightning-out as well in Standalone App. It will work only in one.app container(sf1 or LEX)

Comment: Check Nordine's Post he got it when he previewed it i guess he created a lightning app and added it a tab and then might have previewed it let me do it and check

Comment: It will work if your component added to LEX as a Tab. Nordine added it to the record detail page which runs in one.app container. By seeing tge screenshot it's evident that it's inside one.app

Comment: By the way what is one.app container is it just any base app on which all the lightning tabs are hosted or a specific app

Comment: I see it as a specific app where all the Lightning tabs are hosted.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Preview from Dev Console this won't work (or, as Praveen pointed out from Visualforce), you'd have to test it in lightning experience.

[The documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_showToast.htm) states:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in
>   Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.

I can only assume that Aura preview is not Lightning Experience (would think its to do with the full app framework not being loaded in preview).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to launch the component via app , standard events (toast,  navigateToSobject,  etc)  will be undefined.

var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

toastEvent will have "undefined " always.

Therefore launch your toastComponent in LEX via **app builder** or **lightning quickaction** or drag to detail page to check how it works.

Comment: I think it is a good practice to mention you source when you copy whole answer - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BhBxQAK

Answer (score 0):

It will work now, use below code

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:showToast" type="EVENT,COMPONENT" />
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="num1"/> +
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="num2"/>
    <br/>
    <ui:button label="Add" press="{!c.showToast}"/>
</aura:component>
```